# Linux dd problem on difference result for same blocks

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, dd

I try to run simple test case on linux operating system with dd command .

I create a simple disk image with this command :

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=disk.img bs=1M count=100
```

**This is First Test :**
Now I run this commands :

```
dd if=disk.img of=output_1 bs=1k count=4
dd if=disk.img of=output_2 bs=4k count=1
md5sum output_1 output_2 
bc0245c10ff529042fd2a5335ed1573f  output_1
bc0245c10ff529042fd2a5335ed1573f  output_2
```

You can see ***`output_1`*** and ***`output_2`*** exactly has same md5 hash .

**This is Second Test :**
Now I add skip parameter to dd command :

```
dd if=disk.img of=output_1 skip=1500 bs=1k count=4 
dd if=disk.img of=output_2 skip=1500 bs=4k count=1
c5b0e8dde317c25011b31a5c48580477  output_1
4585d39fcf93cec4abc6c55094aac724  output_2
```

Why result is difference for this blocks ?
What part of my test is wrong ?

Comment: you should also add `iflag=fullblock`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The skip parameter is in (input) blocks, not in bytes, as written in the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/coreutils/dd.1):

> ```
> skip=N    skip N ibs-sized blocks at start of input
> ```

In the first case the skipped part is:

1500 * 1KiB = 1536000 bytes

The second case:

1500 * 4KiB = 6144000 bytes

As long as the involved values divide exactly you can adjust. For the second case using 1500*1k/4k=375 (`skip=375`) will give back the same result as the first case.